# For loop crashing on speech_recognition

Tags: python, amazon-s3, speech-recognition

Python Newbie trying to teach myself how to use Python to run speech_recognition, and Im not having great luck.

The code below runs once and correctly converts a wav file to text, but then it crashes before running the remaining 2 wav files in my S3 bucket. The files are absolutely there:

OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav
OSR_us_000_0011_8k.wav
OSR_us_000_0012_8k.wav

I could use some help fixing it.

Thanks in Advance.

```
import boto3

import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

session = boto3.client('s3',

                    aws_access_key_id= XXXX,

                    aws_secret_access_key=XXXX,

                    region_name='XXXX')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket(mys3bucket)

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():

    with sr.AudioFile(my_bucket_object.key) as source:

        print(my_bucket_object.key)

        audio_data = r.record(source)

        text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)

        print(text)


OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav<br>
Birch canoe slid on the smooth plank glue the sea to a dark blue background it is easy to tell the depth of a well these day the chicken leg of a variegated rice is often served in roundels the juice of lemons mix find the boxes on the side the pump truck the ha grimstead topcon and garbage for hours of Citi workspace a large-sized and stockings in the hearts of cell

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-385959f26678> in <module>
     14 
     15 for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
---> 16     with sr.AudioFile(my_bucket_object.key) as source:
     17         print(my_bucket_object.key)
     18         audio_data = r.record(source)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py in __enter__(self)
    201         try:
    202             # attempt to read the file as WAV
--> 203             self.audio_reader = wave.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
    204             self.little_endian = True  # RIFF WAV is a little-endian format (most ``audioop`` operations assume that the frames are stored in little-endian form)
    205         except (wave.Error, EOFError):

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/wave.py in open(f, mode)
    508             mode = 'rb'
    509     if mode in ('r', 'rb'):
--> 510         return Wave_read(f)
    511     elif mode in ('w', 'wb'):
    512         return Wave_write(f)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/wave.py in __init__(self, f)
    158         self._i_opened_the_file = None
    159         if isinstance(f, str):
--> 160             f = builtins.open(f, 'rb')
    161             self._i_opened_the_file = f
    162         # else, assume it is an open file object already

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'OSR_us_000_0011_8k.wav'
```

Comment: How are you fetching these files from your S3 bucket?  That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: LIke this. It grabs the first file, but then crashes.     session = boto3.client('s3',

                    aws_access_key_id= XXXX,

                    aws_secret_access_key=XXXX,

                    region_name='XXXX')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket(mys3bucket)

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():

Comment: So, you haven't used `my_bucket_object.download_file` to fetch the files?  Printing the `key` doesn't fetch the file.

Comment: Im not trying to download the file. Im trying to run code on the files that are already there. It works on the first file but then crashes.

Comment: Well, the error message strongly indicates that those files are NOT already there.

Comment: for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object.key) results in the following correct list of the S3 contents. OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav
OSR_us_000_0011_8k.wav
OSR_us_000_0012_8k.wav

Comment: I believe that, but that doesn't mean the FILES are local.

Comment: But the first file did get transcribed without using my_bucket_object.download_file. Do you know why the first would work but the second or third dont ?

Comment: It looks to me like 'source' isnt getting updated in the line:audio_data = r.record(source)

Comment: Of course source is not getting updated, because THE FILE IS NOT THERE.  That's what the error has been telling you from the beginning.  The `keys` in your bucket object are the names of the files in the bucket, on Amazon's server.   In order to read the files, they have to be present on YOUR computer, and the only way that can happen is if you specifically download them, and you have not done that.  Do `print(os.listdir('.'))` to see what files are there.

Comment: I was running this on an AWS hosted notebook which does not let you see a file structure (as near as I can tell). Anyway, as you stated the first file transcribed because I forgot that I had downloaded it days ago. The others I had not. Having now download all my files from S3 to a hosted Notebook on AWS, the code runs. Thank you for your patience and help.